# Windows Batch:string replacement

Tags: batch-file

The following batch file accepts a parameter which is a path and filename.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET filename=%~1 
echo !filename!
ENDLOCAL
```

The filename, when received as a parameter will always be formatted using forward slashes.
In order to replace the forwardshlashes with backslashes, I tried this:

```
SET filename=!filename:/=\!
```

But that's not working.
What is the simplest way to do string replacement in a windows batch file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to remove the space after  `=`:

```
SET filename=%~1
```

Otherwise the space will become part of your variable.

To replace / with \ you have to use `%` instead of `!`:

```
SET filename=!filename:/=\!
```

Further, there is nothing in your code that would require `ENABLEEXTENSIONS` so you can skip it.

EDIT:

This is my code of something.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET file=%~1
SET file=!file:\=/!
ECHO !file!
```

Calling the `something.bat ABC/DEF/GHI` results in the output `ABC\DEF\GHI`.

Comment: Made that change, and updated the question, but it does not work. This is what is echoed: /=\

Comment: What are you echoing? `ECHO %filename%` or `ECHO !filename!`? First one is wring, second one is right :)

Comment: Still no success, edited question, !filename! is echoed as /=\

Comment: Edited my post. Try copy paste it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem when you set the variable

```
               v...v. Initial and ending spaces included in value
SET filename =  %~1 
            ^........ Space included in variable name
```

As the variable is not `%filename%`, but `%filename %`, your replacement fails. For a string replacement approach you can use

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "filename=%~1"
    set "filename=%filename:/=\%"
    echo %filename%
```

or, still better, this case can be solved using argument modifiers

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "filename=%~f1"
    echo %filename%
```